# Unable to do route hijacking using umbraco

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I'm trying to create a surface controller which will do the route hijacking.

Here is my controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Umbraco.Web.Mvc;

namespace UmbracoCms.Logic.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : SurfaceController
    {
        public ActionResult Home()
        {
            return Content("Success!");
        }    
    }
}
```

I tried to access to the home controller but it did not work as I would like.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use RenderMvcController instead of SurfaceController

```
public class HomeController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController
{
    public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
    {
        return Content("Success!");
    }    
}
```

Surface controllers are for interacting (like a form submit).

Read more about mapping etc. here: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Routing/custom-controllers